# Checkbox calculation on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following code for calculating checkbox values on a form:
http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RT4XS/

Instead of using the "value" element, is it possible to use another element for calculating the total? For example, the "value" element is already reserved by other plugin and I want to add another element such as "price" or "size" to use it as the item price.

```js
// When the page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function(event) {
        updateTotal();
    });
});

function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
        <b>Cost of Dinner</b>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" price="2" name="Hamburger">Hamburger ($2)<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" price="1" name="French Fries">French Fries ($1)<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" price="3" name="Shake">Shake ($3)<br/> 
        </p>
        </div>
        <p>
            Cost of Dinner <input type="text" name="TotlCost" id="TotalCost" size="10"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I modify the code to use "price" element value or other element value instead of "value" element?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why not make your price as the value my bro?

Comment: @jameshwart. Thank you very much. I just added the "data-price" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). This will keep your HTML valid.

```js
function updateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  
  $("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
  });
  
  $('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}

$('input').on('click', updateTotal);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <b>Cost of Dinner</b>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" data-price="2" name="Hamburger">Hamburger ($2)<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" data-price="1" name="French Fries">French Fries ($1)<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" data-price="3" name="Shake">Shake ($3)<br/> 
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  Cost of Dinner <input type="text" name="TotlCost" id="TotalCost" size="10"/>
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 standard `data-`  attributes. Example

```
<input type="checkbox" value="value_used_by_other" data-price="2" name="Hamburger">
```

To extract price you would do

```
$(this).data('price');
```